# unable to display the background image to full screen of the browser and make it responsive

Tags: html, css

The background image doesn't fits to the browser window's screen. The background image covers only a portion of the screen maintaining its aspect ratio.I want the background image to cover the entire screen on which it runs.Please help!

html

```
<div class="container">
    <h1> GAME</h1>
    <div class="color-overlay"></div>
  </div>
```

css

```
.container {
    background-size: cover;
    background: #000 url(images/group11.jpg);
    color: #fff;
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
  }
.color-overlay {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: blue;
 opacity: .6;
 position: absolute;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you first set `background-size:cover` then you set `background` .

Setting `background` ( which includes repeat,size,position,image etc. ) after the `background-size` will overwrite `cover` with the default setting.

You either set `background-size:cover` **after** the `background` either you set all `background` declarations that you need ( color,repeat,image etc ) separately, either you declare all in one line using just `background`

See below

```css
.container {
  background: #000 url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150);
  /* bg size after */
  background-size: cover;
  color: #fff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  height:100vh;
  
  /* OR set all separately
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150);
  background-color: #000;
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center;
  */
  /* OR set all in one line 
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150) no-repeat scroll center center / cover #000;
  */
  
}

.color-overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  opacity: .6;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1> GAME</h1>
  <div class="color-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you run the snippet, you will see the picture still doesnt cover the full screen. i want it to cover full screen

Comment: @roh_dev added `height:100vh` on the `.container` . See updated answer. Or you could use `height:100%` on `.container` and on `body,html{height:100%}`

Comment: Thanks a lot! really really appreciate it!

Comment: @roh_dev glad i could help. Don't forget to rate my answer as accepted ( the green tick ) . Thanks !

Comment: i had tried body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;height:100%;margin:0;}  earlier but it diidnt work. .But as u suggested height:100vh worked

Comment: yeah. .understood! Thanks and i did upvote ur answer . It wont show though due to less reputations. .