# CSS How to have a background image fully displayed and responsive to the width of the browser

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm sorry as I am aware that this question or similar have been posted

[Fully display background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56619160/fully-display-background-image)

[unable to display the background image to full screen of the browser and make it responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49322443/unable-to-display-the-background-image-to-full-screen-of-the-browser-and-make-it)

And so on... but I am pulling my hair apart.

I'm trying to have the image fit the width size of the browser, but I want it fully displayed. And if I change the size of the browser, I want the image to keep its full size.

I have tried fixing the height of the `.banner` which gives me exactly what I want (height of image for instance as `height : 600px`). But then this height is obviously not responsive if I shorten the width.
Set at 100% doesn't worse neither. I tried 100vh as well. I tried  `background-size:contain;` or `cover`... I'm running out of energy trying to figure this out...

Any ideas?

Thank you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Exoticar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="banner">
<nav>
    <div class="img"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.png"></div>
    <div class="buttons">
    <button> Home </button>
    <button> About </button>
    <button> Services </button>
    <button> Investors </button>
    <button> Contact </button>
    </div>
</nav>
    <div class="centerbanner">
    <h1>CREATING THE FUTURE</h1>
    <p>Your new experience. Your new friend</p>
    <button> Learn More </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

nav {
  height: 65px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: .82;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

nav button {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: .82;
  color: whitesmoke;
  border: none;
}

nav button:hover {
  color: red;
}

.buttons {
  width: 730px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.banner {
  background-image: url('https://wallpaperfx.com/view_image/ferrari-612-black-1366x768-wallpaper-16089.jpg');
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  /* resize: both; */
  /* overflow: scroll; */
}

.centerbanner {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  /* align-self: flex-start; */
}

.centerbanner * {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.centerbanner h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.centerbanner p {
  /*margin-top: 0;*/
  font-size: 20px;
}

.centerbanner button {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
  background-color: red;
  width: fit-content;
  align-self: center;
  padding: 1em 2em;
}

.centerbanner button:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Exoticar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="banner">
    <nav>
      <div class="img"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.png"></div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button> Home </button>
        <button> About </button>
        <button> Services </button>
        <button> Investors </button>
        <button> Contact </button>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="centerbanner">
      <h1>CREATING THE FUTURE</h1>
      <p>Your new experience. Your new friend</p>
      <button> Learn More </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

PS : the image I use isn't the exact same, but is a .png image of 1366 x 612 px. This one is close to that.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I've fully understood. Different devices have different aspect ratios, and of course on desktops for example users can set the viewport to have whatever aspect ratio they like. Therefore no one image can exactly fit all viewports. The best you can do to have full coverage of any screen is to set the background-image to size cover. This will crop the image at top and bottom or at the sides depending on what is needed to cover the viewport.

Comment: I've used this property. My problem is, if I don't set up an absolute height for the div block of the background image, the image is not fully displayed. (missing the bottom of it)

Comment: Are you actually wanting the banner dimensions to fit those of the image rather than the other way round? Ie so if the banner is always 100vw it’s height is 100vw/images aspect ratio?

Comment: that's right, I want to banner to fit the size of picture. And when I change the browser's size, it changes with it.